# Statistical comparison of multiple methods on a single data set

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, validation

I'm trying to optimize and evaluate multiple machine learning methods on a single data set. I know that the "usual" procedure with k-fold cross-validation works as follows:

- 1. Step: Split your data into a training set and a testing set
- 2. Step: To select the best hyperparameters for each method, use the training set and k-fold cross-validation
- 3. Step: Retrain your methods using, first, the best hyperparamters from the previous step and second, the training set
- 4. Step: Calculate the performance metric (e.g., accuracy) on the test set using the model from step 3.

However, when using such a procedure we end up with having only **one observation per method**, and thus, I can't calculate any statistical differences in performance.

That is why I came up with the following procedure to optimize and evaluate my methods:

- 1. Step: Split your data into a training set and a testing set
- 2. Step: To select the best hyperparameters for each method, use the training set and k-fold cross-validation
- 3. Step: For each method, use the *k* models from cross-validation with the best hyperparamter setting from the previous step and estimate their scores on the independent test set.

Thus, we end up having **k observations per method** (compared to having only 1 observation per method in the previous procedure).

1. Question: Is this a valid approach to optimize and evaluate my methods?
2. Question: If this is a valid approach to compare methods which statistical test can I used to look for significant differences in performance?

Comment: Note that any data splitting procedure is likely to be inefficient especially if N is not huge.  But to your question try to simulate Y to create a huge validation sample that can be treated as if it is the entire population, and compare various methods fitted from other independent data and evaluated on the huge validation sample, using a sensitive predictive accuracy metric (e.g., Brier score, logarithmic scoring rule, MSE).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What do you mean by 'inefficient'? Inefficient in terms of I'll lose sample size whenever I split the data? And what do you mean by 'from other independent data'? I don't have any other data sets. That is why I need to compare the performance of multiple classifiers on this single data set.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't write that clearly.  My comments were directed at studying the procedure you are using, not in estimating performance on a single dataset.  Simulations are invaluable for learning because you know the ground truth when simulating data.  "Re-simulations" make simulations realistic by developing a predictive instrument from your data and using it to simulate an unlimited amount of new data for training and especially for testing.

Comment: Regarding performance in your single instance, the comment about inefficiency was referring to the great reduction in sample size both for training and for testing.  Resampling methods (bootstrap or 100 repeats of 10-fold cross-validation) maximize effective sample sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I got the inefficiency part and I totally agree. However, I'm curious whether the second approach - using the k models from k-fold cross validation on the same, independent test set - is a valid approach in evaluating and comparing my methods. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Whenever you have an infinite (for all practical purposes) validation sample then it can be the gold standard for comparing any number of methods.  I usually take n=50,000 or 100,000 to be close enough to infinite.  This applies when doing re-simulation.